# Iptables on a Debian machine, the delete command needs a networking restart to work?

Tags: debian, iptables

I have a big problem with iptables, this the thing I try to make :

PC windows (192.168.1.1) -> (192.168.1.2) PC Linux (192.168.2.1) -> (192.168.2.2) card

I want to forward the messages from Windows to card. I wrote these rules :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.2 -p udp --dport 49000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2:49000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.2.1 -p udp --dport 49001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:49001
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

It works if I restart the card after created the rules, this is not a really big problem.

The bigger one is if I delete a rule, the rule doesn't appear with :

```
iptables -t nat --list
```

but it still work, the messages continue to be forward...

If I want to really delete a rule I need to flush the table (`iptables -t nat -F`), after that to restart the network (`/etc/init.d/networking restart`) and finnaly to re-create the rules I don't want to delete...

I found this in the forum but in my case it's false :
[Page I found here](https://serverfault.com/questions/304216/is-a-reboot-required-after-edit-saving-linux-iptables/304217)

Do you have some ideas? :)

edit 1:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 OK
```

no more iptables rules than the 4 I wrote.

edit 2 :

When I delete the rule in iptables, I can see it after in the conntrack, so I try to remove the rule, I flushed the conntrack, it was empty, but it still doesnt work : the rule comeback in the conntrack when a package arrive.

It's seems that the rules was saved somewhere and the conntrack can find it, but not me... The only way to delete it is to flush itables, and restart the network...

Comment: On the system in the middle, do you have "net.ipv4.ip_forward" enabled?
Do you have /24 networks on your windows and card machine?
I am assuming you have the iptable rules on the linux system, can you provide a routing table as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's a conntrack issue.  Once the connection is considered "established", the NAT table isn't even consulted, and the traffic will continue to pass.  Restarting networking is a brutal way of flushing the conntrack table (because entries get removed when the addresses they relate to get removed); more subtly, there are conntrack table manipulation tools available, but I've never used them so I can't give specific advice on that.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'll try to delete the rule in the conntrack table, I found some commands about that.

Comment: You're right, when I delete the rule in iptables, I see it after in the conntrack, so I try to remove the rule, I flushed the conntrack, it was empty, but it still doesnt work : the rule comeback in the conntrack when a package arrive...

Comment: A new conntrack entry might be established, but it shouldn't be a NAT rule any more.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, I don't understand why this nat rule come back...

Answer (score 0):

Any rules you apply using iptables take affect immediately (loaded in kernel). Most provably you have logical issues in your firewall and/or network configuration. A dump of your iptables rules would be helpful.

Comment: I only have de 4 rules I gave in the first post in all the iptables